# Install SCVMM 2022 agent on AlmaLinux 9 VM

Tags: redhat, system-center, almalinux

I am trying to install SCVMM 2022 agent on AlmaLinux 9.
I discovered that the agent script is trying to use init.d while in AlmaLinux, there is no compatibility with init.d anymore but only systemd.

I updated the install script to copy the agent exec in /etc/systemd/system.
Now, I have a new error "Unable to find service control mechanism".
I understand that the script is unable to register the agent daemon in systemd.
How can I do to get the agent registered.
Have anyone ever have that issue with RedHat9 or any other forks in SCVMM 2022?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) systemd and virtual machines are specifically off topic. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just working on this (literally) right now, and while I can't get you a complete answer, I can tell you I've done the following and gotten it to at least install so I can create the template.  Here's my notes up to this point, after creating the VM and copying the scvmm agent:

- Install initscripts to create /etc/{init.d,rc.d,etc} folders

> sudo yum install initscripts -y

https://centos.pkgs.org/9-stream/centos-baseos-x86_64/initscripts-10.11.1-1.el9.x86_64.rpm.html

- Run install script for scvmm

> sudo ./install scvmmguestagent.1.0.0.544.x64.tar

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/vmm/vm-linux?view=sc-vmm-2022

- Shut down VM in VMware
- Clone to template

I noticed that they don't offer RHEL 9 in their Guest OS Profile, so it may only be half supported.  I'm also using VMware, you may have better luck if you're using Hyper-V